# WSO2 API Manager: Error during Analytics setup + PostgreSQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-streaming-integrator

We are installing WSO2 API Manager 2.6 Analytics using PostgreSQL DB.
When the dashboard component starts we get the following error:

> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.database.query.manager.exception.QueryMappingNotAvailableException: Mapping value for query: 'table_check' not found in Deployment config Map and Component config Map for database type: 'PostgreSQL' and version '9.5.12'

It seems it can't find the PostgreSQL queries.
How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 statistics are not displayed in the APIM Analytics 2.6.0 dashboard, rather as same as the previous product version it is displayed on APIM 2.6.0 Publisher profile. underneath implementation directly access the Store Query AP in APIM Analytics 2.6.0 Worker runtime in order to get the statistics data.

So, in the default analytics scenario, you don't need to deploy the APIM Analytics 2.6.0 dashboard runtime to view the APIM statistics.

To give an answer to your query, unfortunately, there is a limitation in dashboard runtime with Postgres SQL where we need to introduce the compatible queries in here: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-dashboards/blob/master/components/dashboards/org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core/src/main/resources/sql-queries.yaml

or else you can give the compatible queries in the wso2am-analytics-2.6.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml as explained in the doc:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Configuring+Database+Queries#ConfiguringDatabaseQueries-DashboardDashboard

Copy the queries with the above structure under the 'wso2.status.dashboard' namespace.